# pytorch indexing for pixel probabilities

Tags: pytorch

Suppose I need to classify each pixel into one of 3 classes. I wish to get the probability of each pixel. Here is a minimal example. Question is, how do I get those probabilities.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

y = torch.randint(0, 3, (2, 1, 5, 5)) # classes
logits = torch.randn(2, 3, 5, 5) 
prob  = F.softmax(logits, dim=1) # probability map

prob[y] # does not work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html?highlight=gather#torch.gather):

```py
torch.gather(prob,1, y)
```

You `gather` the probabilities along the first dimension according to the indices of `y`.